# Option menu twice option click in one item?

Tags: java, android

I need a help, how to make one item option menu with different function?
example : when i click first R.id.search then show edittext then when i click R.id.search again then edittext hide.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_2, menu);
    return true;
}    

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {

  case R.id.search:
      if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search){ 
      editsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }else{
          editsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
      }
    break;
```

Comment: Do not change the item id, just keep the state in a local variable and select the action in function of that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the current visibility of the `editSearch` view

```
case R.id.search:
    if (editsearch.getVisibility() == View.GONE) 
        editsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        editsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

add global varible:

```
boolean isFirst=true;
```

and first time the click fires set it to false something like that:

```
case R.id.search:
if (isFirst){ 
      isFirst=false;
      editsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }else{
          editsearch.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
      }
    break;
```